# Bash script cd doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell

Part of my bash script is to access a series of folders:

```
 #lsit of folders
locations=("/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314a"
    "/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314b"
    "/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314c")

for i in "${locations[@]}"
do (
    #change to directory

    cd "$i"
    #convert tiff to png
```

However when I received errors:

```
/Users/luna/Documents/Ethan/scripts/microglia.sh: line 16: cd: /Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314a/: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to just cd into that folder on terminal and it absolutely worked. How come it just wont work in a shell script?

Comment: Here's an idea. You should try it on your terminal. These 2 will work: `cd /Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez`, `cd "/Volumes/Israel Hernandez"`. But this one will not work: `cd "/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez"`. The backslash inside double quotes in the assignment of the directories into array `locations` is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the backslash escapes before the spaces since the spaces are already inside a double-quoted string.  Your quoting is correct — rejoice!  Remove the backslashes inside your `""` strings and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly:"No Such file or directory!"
You  can executive the command   "cd /Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314a/"  on the terminal.
if the error is "No such file or directory!",you should carefully check the path.
Don't doubt the script parser itself!Just doubt your code!

Comment: “line 16: cd: /Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314a/"

Comment: “line 16: cd: /Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\  data/3\ month/Mutant/314a/”     carefully check the error of this path!   Copy the  erroried  path  on your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

before you cd command, you should process the escape space in you $i.
here is the code, hope it helps.

```
#lsit of folders
locations=("/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314a"
    "/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314b"
    "/Volumes/Israel\ Hernandez/Quantitative\ Data/Microglia\ data/3\ month/Mutant/314c")

for i in "${locations[@]}"
do (

    #reverse esxape chars such space in you code
    i="echo \$\'"$(echo $i|sed -e 's|\\|\\\\|g')"\'"
    i=$(eval "echo $(eval $i)")
    i=$(eval "echo $(eval $i)")

    #change to directory
    cd "$i"
    #convert tiff to png
```

Comment: That looks like it will work (haven't tried it myself).  I do want to mention you should [be very careful with `eval` to avoid introducing security holes or other problems.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/2877364)